# webm alternative for ios

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, webm

What is .webm (with transparent background/alpha channel) alternative that works on iOS devices?

I have a project that use ffmpeg to create .webm videos with alpha channel/transparent background, but turns out .webm isn't ios supported.

```
const convertedVideoName = `${originalVideoName.split('.')[0]}.webm`;
const newPath = getInternalFilePath(convertedVideoName); // internal local path
const ffmpeg = spawn(
  'ffmpeg',
  [
    '-i',
    originalFile, // <- .mp4
    '-i',
    mattePath,
    '-filter_complex',
    '[0][1]alphamerge,format=yuva420p',
    '-c:v',
    'libvpx',
    '-strict',
    '-2',
    '-auto-alt-ref',
    '0',
    newPath,
  ],
  { shell: true }
);
```

Comment: Does [this](https://kitcross.net/hevc-web-video-alpha-channel/) or [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2050) help?

Comment: I will probably have to use .mov format

Comment: No it doesnt! Thanks muddying the waters

Comment: ffmpeg -y -i color.mp4 -i alpha.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=320x568 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=320:568,setsar=1:1,split[vs][alpha];[0:v][vs]alphamerge[vt];[2:v][vt]overlay=shortest=1[rgb];[rgb][alpha]alphamerge" -shortest -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -alpha_quality 0.75 -vtag hvc1 -pix_fmt yuva420p -an output.mov

use with ffmpeg version 4.

Comment: adjust the sizes too, and run on a Mac hardware. (only way to get hevc_videotoolbox)